# Starting another exe as child process

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services, console-application

Programming - C# .Net

I want to convert a console application as windows service for that found the solution - triggering the console exe by a new service project. but when I did the same, the console application is starting as new Task Process.
Code Snippet for starting the Console application

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"D:\ConsoleTest\bin\Debug\MyConsole.exe";
        Process.Start(path);

    }
```

Is there any way to start the MyConsole.exe as child process of service application?
Currently MyConsole.exe is running as new separate process.

[image]

Comment: BTW:  It is possible to have one application/piece of code that can run as both a console app and a windows service.

Comment: What do you expect from a child process? Try starting the process with ProcessStartInfo and UseShellExecute = false.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that, different exes are different processes, so they will run independently as separate processes.

You can convert your console application to windows service if you want to run that as one process Or run the console application as a service by implementing `ServiceBase`.

**Note**: You can search on the internet that how to run a console application as a window service.